# Selenium issue / java applet

Tags: java, selenium, applet

I am trying to automate the testing of a website and have ran into an issue. What happens is that the url address is entered into the search field but the web page doesn't load fully every time. The issue seems to be a java appled that that isn't fully loaded. If I move the mouse a little bit or press a key will it continue to load fully. This means that I have to sit and watch my tests, if they get stuck will i move the mouse so that they can continue.

How can I avoid moving the mouse when this occurs? Because there is no reason for having automated test cases if you have to watch them.

Answer (score 1):

Which selenium do you use IDE or RC ?

I think maybe you can simulate a mouse move on your script by using moveToElement or type in a rand inpuText to simulate a key press.

Comment: I use the rc server. The problem is that before the site has been loaded do I not get any response while looking for element. And therefore can't I move the mouse over there. Same thing with keys.